# Calling parent constructor within child class

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor, parent

Can anyone explain me why this code is working?

```
<?php

class iParent
{
    private $device;
    private $browser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->device = 'iPad';
        $this->browser = 'Safari';
    }

    public function getDetails()
    {
        return 'Device ' . $this->device . ' ' . 'Browser ' . $this->browser; 
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
class iParentChild extends iParent
{
   public function __construct()
  {
     echo 'IParentChild constructor';
  }

    public function display()
    {
       return $this->getDetails();
    }
}

$obj = new iParentChild;
echo $obj->display();

// Output
Device iPad Browser Safari
```

I thought it should work only if I call `parent::__construct()` (to initialize the parent constructor) in the constructor of the `iParentChild`.

//UPDATE 
I added __construct in iParentChild

Comment: What's the confusion for exactly? You didn't specify `iParentChild` constructor, therefore it inherits the one from the parent class. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iParentChild class does not define `__construct` then it inherits the one from it's superclass, iParent. If it did define `__construct` then that would override the parent's constructor and hence, as stated in your question, would need to call `parent::__construct()`.

EDIT

Note that even if iParentChild *does* override `__construct` without calling the parent constructor there will not be an error in this example. This is because php provides default initialisation of variables in the context in which they are used and here they are used as strings. In practice it is best not to rely on this:

[From the PHP Manual - Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a
>   very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of
>   their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans
>   default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g.
>   used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty
>   array.
>
> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is
>   problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses
>   the same variable name. It is also a major security risk with
>   register_globals turned on. E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of
>   working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of
>   appending elements to the uninitialized array. isset() language
>   construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already
>   initialized.

An attempt to call a method on an uninitialised member object would have resulted in an error.

Comment: Please see the updated version. I added __construct in iParentChild but I stil get no errors.

Comment: I copied your code and the output I get, as expected is: IParentChild constructorDevice Browser

Comment: Yes but now I have constructor in iParentChild. I expected to get an error when this->getDetails() is executed as parent constructor is not initialized.

Comment: Edited answer to provide further explanation